# font-face automatically changes font to uppercase

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to replace the default font type with a separate font in my HTML, and have implemented the following CSS(alongside Django templates)

```
  font-family: "Lovelo-Black";
  src: url("{% static '/fonts/lovelo/Lovelo Black.otf' %}") format("opentype");
  font-size: clamp(8px, 1vw, 14px);
}
```

But the second I do this, my fonts are automatically capitalised, even when caps lock is disabled. Is that a result of the font being used, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The font is only uppercase

Comment: @Sfili_81 The font in particular or the specific typeface I'm using? I got it from [here](https://www.fontfabric.com/fonts/lovelo/)